# Is there any C++ library to work with WMI?

Tags: c++, wmi, static-libraries

I'm working on a big project that have to poll remote WMI counter. I have to code a Win32 app in C++ to query WMI from remote Windows systems. So, Is there any C++ library (free or paid) help me to work with WMI ? Please help me.

Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`WMI Delphi Code Creator`](http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/) to generate [C++ code](http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/wiki/MSCPPDevelopers) to access the WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) classes, events and methods.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are no off the shelf libraries (think STL) for accessing WMI. You'll have to do it manually. There is a [brief outline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389762%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN as to what a program is expected to do in order to access these functions. There is also some example code related to the article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).