# How to use wmi in Ubuntu with C++

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, wmi, wmic

I want to get information from my Client's that running Windows through Linux.

I have several clients that running Windows, and I'm running Ubuntu. I want to make a C++ code, and get information like CPU usage, disk space, etc from my client's.

Is there any way to do that?

I know I can use WMIC (WMI Client) and execute query (WQL) from terminal, but I want to use some libraries in C++ (I use Qt Creator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Create an application using the following library

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=vs.85).aspx

and send this information back to the ubuntu either using sockets or any other ports or simply save it into a txt file and access that file using ftp.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394558(v=vs.85).aspx

[Is there any C++ library to work with WMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052597/is-there-any-c-library-to-work-with-wmi)

Comment: MSDN is for Windows platforms, and C++ that runnig on Windows, so it is easy to use Windows API, but I'm on ubuntu and that API doesn't work for me.

Comment: and use `system()` for executing this commands in your program. system is a system call for using terminal commands.

Comment: Now it is the correct answer, with this linke:krenger.ch/blog/wmi-commands-from-linux